# Java.IO.io Exception Handeling

Tags: java, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

Where do I handle the java.io.IOException exception?

I know the error will occur. As I'm trying to get the application to launch and display a message when no internet connection is found now I'm not sure if this is because of the google.services file or what but I know its associated with the FirebasePushNotification as per my App center log

```
java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
com.google.firebase.iid.zzr.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzr.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzu.then(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113
```

```
JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)
JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)
TaskInvoker.get_RawResult ()
Task.get_Result ()
FirebasePushNotificationManager.OnComplete (Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task)
IOnCompleteListenerInvoker.n_OnComplete_Lcom_google_android_gms_tasks_Task_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_task)
crc6494e14b9856016c30.FirebasePushNotificationManager.onComplete FirebasePushNotificationManager.java:30
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
```

I just have no idea where I'd handle this error to avoid these crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java IOExceptions are Input/Output exceptions (I/O), and they occur whenever an input or output operation is failed or interpreted. 
When writing code that might throw an I/O exception, try writing the code in a `try-catch` block.

Your catch block should look something like this:

```
try {
    //do something
}catch(IOException ex){

    //handle error here
}
```

Comment: Will this function like the normal exception catch or will it only catch IO exceptions and if so how do I check for other errors aswell? And what would be the cause of these usually? I get these most Frequently when I call the onResume() so when I put the app in background and enter again I have no code in my onResume() could that cause it, As i Dont know what to do in the on Resume i'd need the app to just continue nothing to specific needs to continue